# Add image in the header of a model CV (Carmine Benedetto)

Tags: graphics, friggeri-cv

I'm using this model for doing my CV : https://fr.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/extended-fancy-cv-(carmine-benedetto)

I want to insert a picture of me in the cv but the image appears just below the text like this :

[image]

And I would like to have the image on the same line.

This is the code I have :

```
\header{Baptiste }{Vaudey}
      {Analyste Programmeur}

\includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width = 2.5cm, right]{picture.png}
```

And this is the code in the Header :

```
  \newcommand{\header}[3]{%

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=3cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{30pt}{62pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
    \node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
      \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{pblue}%
      \bodyfont #3%
    };

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}
```

Thanks for your answer

EDIT : 
I'm sorry this is my first post on tex.stackexchange, would you like the entire code like this :

```
    %!TEX TS-program = xelatex
    \documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={},
        pdfauthor={},
        pdfsubject={},
        pdfkeywords={},
        colorlinks=false,       % no lik border color
       allbordercolors=white    % white border color for all
    }
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    \RequirePackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{pblue}{HTML}{0395DE}

    \begin{document}

    % Interessing part !

    \header{Vaudey}{Baptiste}
          {Computer Engineer}

    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width = 2.5cm, right]{picture.png}


    % Fake text to add separator      
    \fcolorbox{white}{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    .....
    }}

    % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
    \begin{aside}
      \section{Address}
        Viale Fulvio Testi, 62
        20126, Milano, Italy
        ~
      \section{Tel \& Skype}
        +39 329 7216527
        neoben86
        ~
      \section{Mail}
        \href{mailto:carmine.benedetto@gmail.com}{\textbf{carmine.benedetto@}\\gmail.com}
        \href{mailto:carmine@carminebenedetto.net}{\textbf{carmine@}\\carminebenedetto.net}
        ~
      \section{Web \& Git}
        \href{http://www.carminebenedetto.net}{carminebenedetto.net}
        \href{https://bitbucket.org/neoben}{bitbucket.org/neoben}
        \href{https://github.com/neoben}{github.com/neoben}
        ~
      \section{Programming}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.62]{img/programming.png}
        ~
      \section{OS Preference}
        \textbf{GNU/Linux}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/5stars.png}
        \textbf{Unix}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/4stars.png}
        \textbf{MacOS}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/2stars.png}
        \textbf{Windows}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/1stars.png}
        ~
      \section{Personal Skills}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.62]{img/personal.png}
        ~
    \end{aside}

    \section{Experience}
    \begin{entrylist}
      \entry
        {02/13 - Now}
        {Software Engineer}
        {Fluidmesh Networks SRL, Milano, Italy}
        {Design and development of algorithms, solutions and high speed mobility           schemes for Wireless Mesh Networks. Design and development of embedded software     for Wireless Network devices.\\}
      \entry
        {01/12 - 01/13}
        {Freelance Developer \& Consultant}
        {Icosaedro Solutions}
        {Design and development of Android Applications, Web Solutions, Unix and GNU/Linux software.\\}
        \entry
        {12/09 - 06/09}
        {Project Manager and Webmaster}
        {D.I.D.A.G., Grassano (MT), Italy}
        {Design, development and management of an e-commerce website on Joomla!1.5 CMS platform.\\}
        \entry
        {06/09 - 09/09}
        {Part-time collaboration}
        {Area Sistemi Informatici, Università di Pisa, Italy}
        {Computer technical support. Problem solving related to hardware, software and Operating Systems. Management of the internal network.\\}
        \entry
        {06/09 - 09/09}
        {Internship}
        {Atitlan Engineering SRL, Pisa, Italy}
        {Management and migration of servers. Development of web templates and interfaces. Management of SQL databases.}
    \end{entrylist}

    \section{Education}
    \begin{entrylist}
      \entry
        {2009 - 2012}
        {Master's Degree in Computer Engineering}
        {Università di Pisa, Italy}
        {Curriculum Networking and Multimedia.\\
        Main subjects: Network Applications, Systems Architecture and Security, Mobile Applications, Multemedia Information            Processing.\\
        \emph{Title of the Thesis: "A Handoff Algorithm based on Link Quality Prediction for Mass Transit Wireless Mesh Networks"      .}\\
        \emph{Relators: Prof. Enzo Mingozzi, Ing. Carlo Vallati, Prof. Luciano Lenzini.}\\}
      \entry
        {2005 - 2009}
        {Bachelor's Degree in Computer Engineering}
        {Università di Pisa, Italy}
        {Main subjects: Matematics and Physics, Programming, Operational Research, Telecommunication Systems, Digital and Analogical Electronics.\\
        \emph{Title of the Thesis: "Development, Management and Migrations of web contents and applications".}\\
        \emph{Thesis activity carried out during an internship period at Atitlan Engineering SRL.}\\}
      \entry
        {2000 - 2005}
        {Scientific Disploma.}
        {Liceo Scientifico, Matera, Italy}
        {Scientific Secondary School.\\
        Main subjects: Matematics, Physics, Computer Science.}
    \end{entrylist}

    \section{Certifications}
    \begin{entrylist}
      \entry
        {02/2013}
        {Intro to Computer Science}
        {Udacity. E-learning}
        {\emph{Building a Python Search Engine}}
    \end{entrylist}

    \newpage

    \begin{aside}
    ~
    ~
    ~
      \section{Places Lived}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{img/italia.png}
        ~
      \section{Languages}
        \textbf{Italian}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/5stars.png}
        \textbf{English}\includegraphics[scale=0.40]{img/4stars.png}
    \end{aside}

    \section{Publications}
    C. Benedetto, E. Mingozzi, C. Vallati\\
    \textbf{A Handoff Algorithm based on Link Quality Prediction for Mass Transit Wireless Mesh Networks}\\
    \emph{Proceedings of the 18th IEEE Symposium on Computers and Communications (ISCC 2013), Split, Croatia, July 7-10, 2013}
    \\
    \section{Other Info}
    For the Italian job market:\\
    \emph{Si autorizza il trattamento delle informazioni contenute nel curriculum in conformità alle disposizioni previste dal d.lgs. 196/2003. Si dichiara altresì di essere consapevole che, in caso di dichiarazioni non veritiere, si è passibili di sanzioni penali ai sensi del DPR 445/00 oltre alla revoca dei benefici eventualmente percepiti.}
    \\
    \begin{flushleft}
    \emph{January 14th, 2014}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{flushright}
    \emph{Carmine Benedetto}
    \end{flushright}

    \end{document}
```

EDIT :

I try to use raisebox but it's not working I try this :

```
    \raisebox{-\height}{
    \header
    {Baptiste }{Vaudey}
    {Analyste Programmeur}
    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width = 2.5cm, right]{picture.png}}
```

And this

```
    \header
    {Baptiste }{Vaudey}
    {Analyste Programmeur}
    \raisebox{-\height}{
    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width = 2.5cm, right]{picture.png}}
```

I still got the same problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please supplement the code with a complete (minimal) document, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: I edit my post I give you all the code, I don't know if it's what you want, but thanks for your help

Comment: @VaudeyBaptiste, have a look at this post for how to write a MWE: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that
I did try to download your code and such, but it is too much to go through, especially with .bib files. most likely, this can easily be written as an MWE.

Comment: If you want the code you can follow the link here : https://fr.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/extended-fancy-cv-(carmine-benedetto) it's the model I use

Comment: I try some code but nothing works I'm not an expert in sharelatex, and I just want to add a simple picture in a CV

Comment: Are you using Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX? Your document does not seem to compile using LaTeX and I get a compile error using XeLaTeX...

Comment: Escuse me I didn't mention it i'm using shareLatex

Comment: Lose the blank line.  The picture is currently in a different paragraph from the text.  If you want to align tops, you will need to use \raisebox{-\height}{...}

Comment: I try to use the raisebox I edit my post but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would edit the `\header` code and add something like the following:

```
\node [anchor=north] at (name.east) {%
      \includegraphics[height=2.5cm, width = 2.5cm, right]{picture.png}%
    };
```

You can adjust the position with `[xshift=5em]` after `(name.east)`